# Returning a new value for my string variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to update my string variable then return it to be printed.

```
race = 'human'
age = int(x)
def aging(age, maturity):
    if x < 13:
        maturity = 'Child'
    elif x>13 and x<18:
        maturity = 'Teenager'
    elif x>18 and x<65:
        maturity = 'Adult'
    elif x>65 and x<99:
        maturity = 'Senior'
    else:
        maturity = 'Dead'
aging(age, maturity)
x=int(input('Please enter age: '))
print ("Age is",age)
print ("You are a "+maturity)
```

The end product, however, is always

```
Please enter age: 9
Age is 9
You are a none
```

How can I get the maturity string to update?

Comment: Please include the complete code. There's a closure of the variable `x` but I don't see `x` defined anywhere.

Comment: @Chris that is not the problem, `aging` might as well return something, if he does not define `maturity` in the outer scope it will keep being `None`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's address your program as a whole -- the major issue I see is that your data is embedded in your code.  Let's separate out the data to simplify the code:

```
MATURITIES = {
    'a Child': (0, 12),
    'a Teenager': (13, 17),
    'an Adult': (18, 64),
    'a Senior': (65, 99),
}

def aging(age):
    for maturity, (lower, upper) in MATURITIES.items():
        if lower <= age <= upper:
            return maturity

    return 'Dead'

age = int(input('Please enter age: '))

print("Your age is", age)
print("You are", aging(age))
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend your function to return maturity.

You can `global` the variable, but it is considered a bad practice.

I did a few corrections on your code, it should work fine like this:

```
def aging(age):
    if age < 13:
        maturity = 'Child'
    elif age >= 13 and age <18:
        maturity = 'Teenager'
    elif age >= 18 and age <65:
        maturity = 'Adult'
    elif age >= 65 and age < 99:
        maturity = 'Senior'
    else:
        maturity = 'Dead'
    return maturity


age = int(input('Please enter age: '))
print ("Age is", age)
print ("You are a", aging(age))
```

Comment: When I input 18, this code prints `"You are a Dead"` -- a questionable result in multiple ways.

Comment: That's because in your code, you chose what mautiry is if the user inout less than 18, or more than 18, you didn't add what would happen if the user input exactly 18. I fixed my code :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to refactor your code - remove `x`, change where you define variables/take input, and `return` something (`maturity`):

```
def aging(age):
    if age < 13:
        maturity = 'Child'
    elif age > 13 and age < 18:
        maturity = 'Teenager'
    elif age > 18 and age < 65:
        maturity = 'Adult'
    elif age > 65 and age < 99:
        maturity = 'Senior'
    else:
        maturity = 'Dead'
    return maturity
age = int(input('Please enter age: '))
maturity = aging(age)
print ("Age is" + age)
print("You are a " + maturity)
```

Output:

```
Please enter age: 9
Age is 9
You are a Child
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `return`

```
def aging(age, maturity):
    if x < 13:
        maturity = 'Child'
    elif x>13 and x<18:
        maturity = 'Teenager'
    elif x>18 and x<65:
        maturity = 'Adult'
    elif x>65 and x<99:
        maturity = 'Senior'
    else:
        maturity = 'Dead'
    return age, maturity

race = 'human'
age = int(input('Please enter age: '))
age, maturity = aging(age, maturity)

print ("Age is",age)
print ("You are a "+maturity)
```

Comment: Yes there is no need unless you plan to change it inside your function